# Rails, jQuery, Ajax create and update.js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Alright. I am working with RoR and jQuery and I have already got my update and create links working and functioning with their .js.erb files.  The problem arises when in create with this line of code.

```
#create.js.erb
$("#promo_types").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "promotion_type"))%>");
```

it is throwing an error: *You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each*

```
#index.erb
<div id="promo_types">
  <%= render :partial => "promotion_type" %>
</div>

#_promotion_type
 <% @promotion_types.each do |@promotion_type| %>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td width="200"><%=h @promotion_type.name %></td>
      <td width="20"><a class="Edit<%=h @promotion_type.id %>" href="#"><img src="/images/pencil.png" alt="Edit" title="Edit"  /></a></td>
      <td width="20"><%= link_to(image_tag('/images/bin.png', :alt => 'Remove', :title => "Remove"), @promotion_type, :class => "deleteCategory") %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     <div id="popupEdit<%=h @promotion_type.id %>" class="popupEdit">
    <a class="popupClose<%=h @promotion_type.id %>" id="popupClose">x</a>
    <%= render :file => 'promotion_types/edit' %></div>
  <% end %>
```

It doesn't like that first line of code of the partial when I try to append the row using ajax.

My only other question is concerning my update.js.erb. I works fine. If i click edit and update it updates the changes, but I don't see them till I refresh the page. I don't want to .append the partial because the would add the edit to the bottom of the list. Do I use a .html to refresh my partial thru AJAX?

EDIT:

```
#full create.js.erb

$("#promo_types").append(<% escape_javascript(render(:partial => "promotion_type"))%>");
  $("new_promotion_type")[0].reset();
  $(".addtoggle01").toggle();
  $(".addtoggle01").before('<div id="notice">Your promotion type has been successfully submitted.</div>');
```

It resets my form, hides the form, and displays the notice, but it isn't appending anything and not throwing any errors either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `_promotion_type` partial you are looping through `@promotion_types` and it sounds like this instance variable is not getting set in the `create` action.

From the name, it sounds like that partial should only display one promotion type, not many. So move the loop outside of the partial. I recommend using the `:collection` and `:object` options to pass the model to the partial.

```
# index.html.erb
<div id="promo_types">
  <%= render :partial => "promotion_type", :collection => @promotion_types %>
</div>

# _promotion_type.html.erb
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="200"><%=h promotion_type.name %></td>
    <td width="20"><a class="Edit<%=h promotion_type.id %>" href="#"><img src="/images/pencil.png" alt="Edit" title="Edit"  /></a></td>
    <td width="20"><%= link_to(image_tag('/images/bin.png', :alt => 'Remove', :title => "Remove"), promotion_type, :class => "deleteCategory") %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="popupEdit<%=h promotion_type.id %>" class="popupEdit">
<a class="popupClose<%=h promotion_type.id %>" id="popupClose">x</a>
<%= render :file => 'promotion_types/edit' %></div>

# create.js.erb
$("#promo_types").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "promotion_type", :object => @promotion_type))%>");
```

As for your second question, yes. You can assign a specific ID to each record and replace that using the `.html` method.

```
# update.js.erb
$("#promo_type_<%= @promotion_type.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "promotion_type", :object => @promotion_type))%>");
```

Comment: i threw the loop outside the partial and I wasn't getting that error anymore. Thanks. But my .append and .html are having no effect at all. I'll make an edit it show you code.

Comment: Make sure to add the equal sign in `<%=` before escape_javascript.

Comment: I think that was there. The code was on another computer so I'd was typing it over and might have overlooked it. I'll check tomorrow when I get back to work.

Comment: If that isn't the problem try something like FireBug to ensure there aren't any javascript errors. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: I use firebug all the time. Just got back to work and I was missing that = so that works now! Thanks a lot for all the help!